# Linear gradient shadow color not working in Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a surrounding shadow color as a linear gradient. However, I am stuck to the default Swiftui colors and would like to use a linear gradient. I am getting an error that's prompting me to change the linear gradient to a simple color. Here's an example of my code...

```
struct Rectangle: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .fill(.regularMaterial)
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .opacity(0.4)
                Text("Search")
                    .opacity(0.4)
                    .font(.title2)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 60)
//where the problem is occurring...
        .shadow(color: LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.purple, Color.orange, Color.red]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing), radius: 10)
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 40)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.vertical, 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: [See this tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/plus/swiftui-special-effects/shadows-and-glows) by Paul Hudson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
extension View {
    func multicolorGlow() -> some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<2) { i in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: 
[Color.blue, Color.purple, Color.orange, Color.red]), center: .center))
                    .frame(width: 400, height: 300)
                    .mask(self.blur(radius: 20))
                    .overlay(self.blur(radius: 5 - CGFloat(i * 5)))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use like this.

```
    ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .fill(.regularMaterial)
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .opacity(0.4)
                Text("Search")
                    .opacity(0.4)
                    .font(.title2)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 60)
        .multicolorGlow() //remove the shadow and add this view 
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.vertical, 10)
```

Comment: that's adding the shadow to the letters, I was looking for the shape