# Dynamically set frame dimensions in a view extension

Tags: swiftui

I've been playing around with giving views a gradient shadow (taken from [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/plus/swiftui-special-effects/shadows-and-glows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71279352/linear-gradient-shadow-color-not-working-in-swiftui)) and while these achieve most of what I need, they seem to have a flaw: the extension requires you to set a `.frame` height, otherwise the gradient looks really desaturated (as it's taking up the entire height of the device screen). It's a little hard to describe, so here's the code:

```swift
struct RainbowShadowCard: View {
    @State private var cardGeometryHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State private var cardGeometryWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is a card, it's pretty nice. It has a couple of lines of text inside it. Here are some more lines to see how it scales.")
                .font(.system(.body, design: .rounded).weight(.medium))
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Color.black
                    .onAppear {
                        cardGeometryHeight = geo.size.height
                        cardGeometryWidth = geo.size.width
                        print("H: \(cardGeometryHeight), W: \(cardGeometryWidth)")
                    }
            }
        }
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous))
        .padding()
        .multicolorGlow(cardHeight: cardGeometryHeight, cardWidth: cardGeometryWidth)
    }
}

extension View {
    func multicolorGlow(cardHeight: CGFloat, cardWidth: CGFloat) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<2) { i in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(
                        LinearGradient(colors: [
                            .red,
                            .green
                        ], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                    )
                    // The height of the frame dictates the saturation of
                    // the linear gradient. Without it, the gradient takes
                    // up the full width and height of the screen, resulting in
                    // a washed out / desaturated gradient around the card.
                    .frame(height: 300)
                    // My attempt at making the height and width of this view
                    // be based off the parent view
                    /*
                    .frame(width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight)
                     */
                    .mask(self.blur(radius: 10))
                    .overlay(self.blur(radius: 0))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RainbowShadowCard_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RainbowShadowCard()
    }
}
```

I've managed to successfully store the `VStack` height and width in `cardGeometryHeight` and `cardGeometryWidth` states respectfully, but I can't figure out how to correctly pass that into the extension.

In the extension, if I uncomment:

```
.frame(width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight)
```

The VStack goes to a square of 32x32.

[image]

---

##### Edit

For the sake of clarity, the above solution "works" if you don't use a frame height value for the extension, *but* it doesn't work very nicely. Compare the saturation of the shadow in this image to the original, and you'll see a big difference between a non framed approach and a framed approach. The reason for this muddier gradient is the extension is using the screen bounds for the linear gradient, so our shadow gradient isn't getting the benefit of the "start" and "end" saturation of the red and green, but the middle blending of the two.

[image]

Comment: I tested it without both `frame` modifiers, it works great!

Comment: It works, but the gradient is super desaturated, I'll add additional context to my original post.